# How to statically link portaudio?

Tags: c++, static-linking, portaudio

I wanted to write some program using [portaudio](http://portaudio.com) library. I downloaded the source, opened the cmake project and builded both static(libportaudio_static.a) and dynamic(libportaudio.dll and libportaudio.dll.a) files.

Then, I created c++ project with just main file, where I tried to print out the version of portaudio library. When I used dynamic linking, it worked, but I can't seem to use the static one. It gives me undefined reference to the `Pa_GetVersion()` method.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Clion and building it with CMake. I have Windows 10.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(snoozeRec)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
# first way i tried to use static library
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-Lportaudio_static")

add_executable(
    snoozeRec
    ${SOURCE_FILES}
    #portaudio.h
    # second way i tried to use static library
    #${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libportaudio_static.a
)

target_link_libraries(snoozeRec ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libportaudio.dll)
```

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "portaudio.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Version of portAudio: " << Pa_GetVersion() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I put all the files in the same directory.

Trying to use `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libportaudio_static.a` in `add_executable`, or `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-Lportaudio_static")`
 gives me this error:

C:/Users/duso/ClionProjects/snoozeRec/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Pa_GetVersion'

If i try @alex-zywicki 's suggestion, using `target_link_libraries(snoozeRec ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libportaudio_static.a)`, it gives me bunch of undefined references:

```
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_util.c.obj): In function `PaUtil_GetTime':
C:/portaudio/src/os/win/pa_win_util.c:154: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `QueryInputWaveFormatEx':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:539: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInOpen@24'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:555: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `QueryOutputWaveFormatEx':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:565: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutOpen@24'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:581: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `QueryWaveInKSFilterMaxChannels':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:676: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInMessage@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:685: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInMessage@16'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `InitializeInputDeviceInfo':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:715: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetDevCapsW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `QueryWaveOutKSFilterMaxChannels':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:806: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutMessage@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:815: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutMessage@16'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `InitializeOutputDeviceInfo':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:848: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetDevCapsW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `PaWinMme_Initialize':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1020: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInMessage@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1024: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutMessage@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1028: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetNumDevs@0'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1032: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetNumDevs@0'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `InitializeWaveHandles':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1904: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInOpen@24'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1910: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutOpen@24'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1950: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1954: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `TerminateWaveHandles':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1984: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInClose@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:1991: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutClose@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2002: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2006: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `InitializeWaveHeaders':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2093: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInPrepareHeader@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2097: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2103: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutPrepareHeader@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2107: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `TerminateWaveHeaders':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2143: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInUnprepareHeader@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2145: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutUnprepareHeader@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `AdvanceToNextInputBuffer':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2750: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInAddBuffer@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2756: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `AdvanceToNextOutputBuffer':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2777: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutWrite@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:2783: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `ProcessingThreadProc':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3012: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetPosition@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `StartStream':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3279: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInAddBuffer@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3283: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3296: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutPause@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3299: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3367: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutWrite@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3371: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3432: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInStart@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3437: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3447: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutRestart@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3450: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `StopStream':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3582: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutReset@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3586: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3595: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInReset@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3599: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj): In function `AbortStream':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3641: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutReset@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3644: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3654: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInReset@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wmme/pa_win_wmme.c:3657: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetErrorTextW@12'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj): In function `BuildFilterList':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3089: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsW@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3105: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces@20'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3112: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceAlias@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3126: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceAlias@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3152: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3169: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces@20'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3175: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceAlias@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3184: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceAlias@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3200: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceAlias@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3209: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW@24'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3225: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW@28'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3243: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiOpenDeviceInterfaceRegKey@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3304: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj): In function `ScanDeviceInfos':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3468: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInMessage@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3471: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInMessage@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3473: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutMessage@16'
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:3476: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutMessage@16'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj): In function `BumpThreadPriority':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:5535: undefined reference to `_imp__timeBeginPeriod@4'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj): In function `DropThreadPriority':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:5561: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4'
../libportaudio_static.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj): In function `GetCurrentTimeInMillisecs':
C:/portaudio/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c:5866: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0
```

Comment: a dll file is a dynamic library. You need to build portAudio from source as a static library (`.a` or `.lib` files). Therefore you must run `configure` with `--enable-static --disable-shared` (the last one is optional)

Comment: i did build both static and dynamic versions(you see, i have both dll and .a files), the portAudio's cmakelists had two configurations.

Comment: Then links against the `.a` file, not the `.dll`

Comment: when i try to link against .a file(and comment out the dynamic linking) with first or second method, it gives me the same one error: undefined reference to `Pa_GetVersion'

Comment: did you check if `Pa_GetVersion` even is in the lib?

Comment: Do you mean in the .a file, or in the header? In header, yes it is there.

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: i am using Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, i managed to resolve the issue. I asked my supervisor at school and he advised me to add the whole portaudio source to my project and add its cmakelists into mine. The resulting CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(snoozeRec)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory("C:\\portaudio" asdf)

add_executable(
        snoozeRec
        main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(snoozeRec portaudio_static)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing:

```
target_link_libraries(snoozeRec${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libportaudio.dll)
```

With:

```
target_link_libraries(snoozeRec${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libportaudio_static.a)
```

Comment: i tried, it says: *** No rule to make target '../libportaudio.a', needed by 'snoozeRec.exe'.  Stop.
Probably because the file is called libportaudio_static.a. Trying with this name instead gives huge number of undefined reference errors

Comment: Where is the library located relative to your source code?

Comment: everything related is in the same directory; CMakeLists.txt, main.cpp, libportaudio_static.a, portaudio.h

Comment: It could be worthwhile if you posted the exact linker errors as well?

Comment: I have edited the question and written out the errors i get in specific cases

Comment: Try installing asio and then building portaudio with asio support. My guess is that there may be an issue with which API portaudio is using. All of your link errors seem to be related to the wmme API

Comment: Are you sure? How come that it does work with dynamic linking?

Comment: You get a huge amount of errors because portaudio_static needs to be linked against some libraries too, i guess. Either build the dependencies also static or link them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The `timeXXX` and `waveXXX` symbols come from the [`WinMM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/user-mode-wdm-audio-components) library and the `SetupXXX` symbols come from the [`Setup API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/setup-api-portal). Here is a minimalistic CMakeLists.txt that compiles fine with MinGW and PortAudio v19:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(test-portaudio-windows)

set(PORTAUDIO_ROOT C:/CPP/portaudio)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PORTAUDIO_ROOT}/include)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PORTAUDIO_ROOT}/lib)
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -static)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE portaudio_static winmm setupapi)
```